# Swift: How to implement a login storyboard?

Tags: swift, authentication, storyboard

I have two different storyboards:

- Mainstoryboard: SWrevealViewController (major part of the app)
- Loginstoryboard: Login/Register Controllers

The Loginstoryboard should be used when the user is not logged in or the user logged out. Then there should be a segue to the Mainstoryboard.

How could I implement it in swift?

Looking forward to your answers!
Jan

Comment: You can try the [AuthNavigation](https://github.com/columbbus/AuthNavigation) framework. It helps you to present you login view controller over your SWrevealViewController. It also organizes a loading page in order to accomplish auto login, if you need to contact a server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried switching your `rootViewController` in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Assuming `Mainstoryboard` has your `rootViewController`:

```
if userIsNotLoggedIn {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Loginstoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let loginController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginNavigationController") as UINavigationController
    window?.rootViewController = loginController
}
```

To switch view controllers once logged in you can do this:

```
func loggedIn() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainVC") as UIViewController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainController
}
```

Comment: I made a quick example here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5296996/LoginExample.zip

Comment: damn nice!!! Don't know how I could thank you!
Do I have to pay attention for logout or further segues between storyboards? For example if login was successful, how do I switch to the other storyboard ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a method to call if you're logged in. If you're looking at my example, you just have to add the `MainVC` storyboard ID in `Main.storyboard` for it to work.