# iOS Storyboard change initial view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've been trying to change the initial view in app delegate by putting this code

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userId"]) {
    LogInViewController* lvc = [[LogInViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: lvc animated:YES];
}else {
    PerfilViewController *pvc = [[PerfilViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: pvc animated:YES];
}
```

i have swrevealviewcontroller in my storyboard as its shown beneath, the red one is the one when its not logged in and the blue one is when its logged in

[image]

Comment: Whats exactly the problem? Why dont changing the initial ViewController in the storyboard?

Comment: so it do make the segue if it has user defaults of the userid but it throws this

Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Instead of having multiple arrows, have only one that points to the very first view (LogInViewController). Then, in the `viewDidLoad` function of LogInViewController, place your checker code. You could then have a segue from LogInViewController over to PerfilViewController that is performed if the user is logged in; otherwise, stay on LogInViewController.

```
viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userId"]){
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toProfile" sender: self];
}
```

Comment: i do have that one, but it throws me this and i wanted to get rid of them
2015-07-01 13:32:27.124 BarApp[872:69539] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <LogInViewController: 0x16653520>.
2015-07-01 13:32:43.540 BarApp[872:69539] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SWRevealViewController: 0x16648aa0>.

Comment: There was a question similar to yours a while back. Maybe this might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171723/swift-how-to-implement-a-login-storyboard/28179052#28179052