# iOS login/auto-login and logout flow

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have an ios application that I am trying to implement the login/auto-login and signout process. I was wondering what is the best way to design storyboards to do so. Right now I have a login view controller and when the user logs in it instantiates the main view controller which is a tabbar controller. On signout I want to unwind back to the login view controller. This works when I go through the login process but if I auto-login to the main view controller then it doesn't work because it is not presented modally.

Comment: You could try the [AuthNavigation](https://github.com/columbbus/AuthNavigation) framework. It organizes the login including auto-login with a loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to achieving the auto-login/signout experience as you described.

One way uses `Storyboard References` to segue between storyboards: one for login, one for the main tab bar.

For example:

1. Create a Login.storyboard file
2. Load the `Login` storyboard first by setting the `Main Interface` value to `Login` in your project's target settings
3. Drag a `Storyboard Reference` object onto the storyboard, and create a segue to it
4. Using the attribute inspector, make sure the Storyboard reference is set to Main (it will initialize the Main storyboard's initial view controller by default)
5. Now in the `Main` storyboard, drag another `Storyboard Reference` in and create a segue to it (use attribute inspector to set reference to Login)
6. When you want to log out, perform a call on segue that refers to the Login storyboard reference.

Also, here's a similar question (possible duplicate) regarding a login storyboard flow: [Swift: How to implement a login storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171723/swift-how-to-implement-a-login-storyboard)

Feel free to ask for any help setting this up. Hope this helps.

Comment: When you logout what kind of segue is it? If it is a push then it continuously pushes views to the stack.

Comment: Great point, @ngumbo. I would use a modal segue for navigating to the login view since it doesn't really have any relationship as far as data is concerned to the "parent" or main tab view.